# Issue with AutoMapper 11 and static props

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper 11 on .NET 6 and I am experiencing an unexpected behavior when mapping classes containing static props or static constructors:

```cs
public class Source
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}

public class Target
{
    private static readonly string PREFIX = "TEST_";

    // or:
    //private static readonly string PREFIX;
    //static Target()
    //{
    //    PREFIX = "TEST_";
    //} 

    public Target(string prop)
    {
        this.Prop = PREFIX + prop;
    }

    public string Prop { get; private set; }
}
```

AutoMapper configuration:

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
              .ConstructUsing(s => new Target(s.Prop))
);
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Usage:

```cs
var target = mapper.Map<Target>(source);
```

Expected behavior:

`target.Prop == "TEST_VALUE"`

Actual behavior:

`target.Prop == "VALUE"` (`PREFIX == null` when `Target` ctor is executed)

See the issue in action here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/MQhcOq

> Since I'm having issues adding AutoMapper on a new fiddle on dotnetfiddle, I have been forced to fork an existing fiddle with AutoMapper 10 and .NET Framework 4.7, but the same is happening with AutoMapper 11 on .NET 6.

Am i missing something?

I suspect AutoMapper is reflecting on the types and is missing the static features of the `Target` class, but I don't know if this should be considered an AutoMapper bug or an intended behavior.
If so, what is the "right way" to handle such cases?

Comment: Remove `ConstructUsing`. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu unfortunately it doesn't seem to make things better:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/nA90e3

Comment: You need AM 11.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I can confirm that It Works On My Machine™ with AutoMapper 11!
I don't understand why `ConstructUsing` behaves differently, though, and if this is its expected behavior or if I should open an issue about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As prosed by @LucianBargaoanu in comments, the solution is twofold:

- ensure you are using AutoMapper 11+
- remove `ConstructUsing` and let AutoMapper automatically map `source.Prop` to the `prop` parameter of `Target` ctor:

  ```cs
  var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
           // .ConstructUsing(s => new Target(s.Prop))
  );
  ```

I still don't understand why `ConstructUsing` is skipping static props initialization and if this behaviour is expected.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).